# mysql create table script fails - error 150

Tags: mysql

I forward engineered a script from a model I created in WorkBench, but the script keeps failing.  It fails on the second create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `myDatabase`.`UserProfile` (

 `ProfileId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `FirstName` VARCHAR( 45 ) NULL ,
 `LastName` VARCHAR( 45 ) NULL ,
 `Gender` CHAR( 1 ) NULL ,
 `DOB` DATETIME NULL ,
 `HairColor` VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL DEFAULT  'No Answer',
 `EyeColor` VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL DEFAULT  'No Answer',
 `Height` VARCHAR( 10 ) NULL DEFAULT  'No Answer',
 `Weight` VARCHAR( 45 ) NULL DEFAULT  'Average',
 `UserId` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `ProfileId` ) ,
CONSTRAINT  `FK_User_Profile` FOREIGN KEY (  `UserId` ) REFERENCES  `OurAgreement`.`UserAccount`     (
`UserId`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I believe error 150 is a foreign key issue.  The table associated with this FK is create first in the script, so it exists before this constraint is attempted.  Here is the DDL for that table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydatabase`.`UserAccount` (
  `UserId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Login` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL ,
  `Password` CHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Any ideas what is going on?

EDIT============================

table with 2 FKs:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `MyDatabase`.`Answer` (

 `AnswerId` INT NOT NULL ,
  `QuestionId` INT NOT NULL ,
 `ProfileId` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `AnswerId` ) ,
INDEX  `ProfileId_idx` (  `ProfileId` ASC ) ,
INDEX  `QuestionId_idx` (  `QuestionId` ASC ) ,
CONSTRAINT  `FK_Question_Answer` FOREIGN KEY (  `QuestionId` ) REFERENCES  `MyDatabase`.`Question` (
`QuestionId`
) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
CONSTRAINT  `FK_Answer_Profile` FOREIGN KEY (  `ProfileId` ) REFERENCES  `MyDatabase`.`UserProfile` (
`ProfileId`
) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
`UserId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

is in your original table, you need exact same syntax in derived table:

```
`UserId` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL
```

should be

```
`UserId` INT NOT NULL
```

---

Also, you need to index the field `UserId` in both tables. Since it is **PRIMARY** in one, so no need there. In another add:

```
INDEX `uid`( `UserId` )
```

Comment: here you go, the second part will do it.

Comment: @Sebas Both of them are necessary ^_^

Comment: yes you are right, I actually meant the second part would finish solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I knew about the datatypes having to match, must say I am red faced about that.  Didn't know about the need to index on the foreign table, so thank you.  If I have a table with 2 FKs in it, would I then have 2 indexes plus the PK on that?  Example added above.

Comment: @teahou Yes. All FK must be indexed in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `myDatabase`.`UserProfile`
```

you reference table in database `OurAgreement`:

```
REFERENCES  `OurAgreement`.`UserAccount`
```

But the table `UserAccount` you create earlier is in `mydatabase`:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydatabase`.`UserAccount`
```